# calculating the size of the array in c, given only a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char* username
```

is a pointer to the beginning of a character array (in c).

How do I calculate the size of the array, is there is function that can do it?

Comment: if it is null terminated, use `strlen`

Comment: As perreal said, if it is NUL terminated, use strlen. If it is allocated using malloc, you may be able to use some non-standard way to look in the malloc system's internal data. Otherwise, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use strlen(username). But the array has to terminated by '\0'. Otherwise you cannot do that.

Comment: That doesn't give the size of the array; that gives the length of the null-terminated string IN the array.  IF you trust the array to be at least as large as the string is long (+ '\0') then you can get a minimum length of the array, but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. If this is an array you allocated, you should have the size of it to start with. For what C and the compiler know, this is just a pointer.

Comment: I do not allocate the size, this is in a function, all i have is a pointer to the beginning

Comment: If this is your function, add an argument that will contain the length of the array.

Comment: the string is inputed from command-line, i don't want to mess it up by asking for the size as well

Comment: I didn't know it is a string, as you didn't specify it :)

Answer (score -1):

If this is a null-terminated string, use strlen to count it's non-null characters, then the array length is at least length + 1 characters.

If you have the array base pointer, you could use sizeof(pointer) to get the size allocated to it by the memory manager.

Comment: That's not how `sizeof` works. `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: You are correct, you could use sizeof for arrays though. Like char my_string[500]; and then sizeof(my_string) will return 500. But since the OP conext is inside a function, that won't work.